# What is a way to fill a multiline editbox with line of text

Tags: .net, c++, multiline, editbox

What im after is a greyed out editbox you see at the bottom of some programs.
A list of results.
Im having problems having the text properly formatted.

so starting from scratch, how is it usually done?

The filling of the half page sized editbox with text.

one big long string with line breaks?

Results->Text = System::Convert::ToString(Var) ;

that seems to be the only way i can input to the editbox
but i cant seem  to build a multiline string that that line will accept.

Comment: what???  what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET or WinAPI? Don't add too much tags. In Win32 dialog template, I use the following styles to create such editbox: Auto HScroll false, Auto VScroll false, Horizontal Scroll false, Multiline true, Read Only true, Vertical Scroll true.

You can add new information by concatenating new text with existing. If you want new line, add "\n". Long lines are wrapped. To scroll down automatically post to this textbox WM_VSCROLL message with SB_BOTTOM parameter.